# squashing commits all the way to the initial leaves 2 commits

Tags: git, git-squash

I am learning git and trying out squashing. I'd like to squash all commits on the master and be left only with initial one. For example, my commit history looks like this:

```
2c825e339b60702b7b48c2ea022e473341d89a7d (HEAD -> master) another edit
f676a10db6a0cfe3cebb8f84aad971b481483181 second file
dc55b957a94bc4a3d6c1b6d8c134407aa4c8316c initial
```

After that I ran `git rebase -i dc55b957a94bc4a3d6c1b6d8c134407aa4c8316c`

The usual way described all over the net is to replace every `pick` with `squash`, but the first one. After doing that I am presented with this commit history:

`2067070140c38f8ecf5f70894e6267bfee614d85 (HEAD -> master) second file
dc55b957a94bc4a3d6c1b6d8c134407aa4c8316c initial`

How come the `squash` didn't work all the way to the initial commit?

Moreover, if I run the same squash command again, there is only 1 `pick statement` in the interactive window. Changing it to `squash` triggers error and leaving it to `pick` does nothing. I have found

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git commit -m "1.0.0"
```

to be an effective way of squashing only 2 commits. How exactly can I use the `git rebase --squash` to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit you specify in the rebase command is the *parent* of the first commit you want to modify or move. This is difficult for the first commit of the repository as it doesn’t have any parents. Instead you can use the `--root` option:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

This should give you all the commits.

Answer (score 1):

You had to do `git reset --soft HEAD~2` and then do `git commit --amend -m 1.0.0`